# differences between binding and not binding parameter at function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

What are the differences between the followings:

**Method 1:**

```
(function( $, window, document, undefined ) {
.......
})( jQuery, window, document );
```

---

**Method 2:**

```
(function( $, window, document, undefined ) {
.......
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

In both functions, there will be local variables for `$`, `window`, `document` and `undefined`

Inside the first function they will have the passed in values (except for `undefined`, which will be undefined).

Inside the second function, they will be undefined (and still mask the global variables with the same name).

Answer (score 0):

You question makes no sense with the code examples you have given. What makes sense though, is

```
(function( $, window, document, undefined ) {
  $("#foo").something();
  document.createElement("bar");
  // ..
})( $, window, document );
```

vs.

```
(function() {
  $("#foo").something();
  document.createElement("bar");
  // ..
})();
```

In the second function, when `$`, `window`, `document` are accessed, the first lookup of those identifiers happens in the function scope – and since they are not found there, the JS engine has to look “further up” in the chain to see whether it finds object for those identifiers there. It will find them, of course (let’s assume here jQuery was available via the `$` object) – `window` is the global object, `$` is and object under `window`, and `document` does also exist outside of the function.

Now, in the first function, those objects are passed as parameters into the function, so they are accessible directly within the function scope – the engine does not have to go on the search for them outside of this scope, those identifiers can be resolved right there.

This is an optimization technique, to speed up lookup times for those identifiers. It is *micro optimization* though – so in most cases there will be no noticeable or even measurable difference. Nevertheless, this pattern has become quite a common one.